# rotating only the text (not the div) in a div element

Tags: html, css, text

I am trying to create a webpage with a lot of div elements whose positions and size are created separately. Next, I want to insert text into those elements so I use JS to put the text in the innerHTML. Is there a way here that I can rotate just the text by 90degrees (and not the div itself since I don't want to change the position and orientation of the div elements?

I tried
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
in CSS but they all rotate the divs themselves and not just the text.

Any idea if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this link:
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation
Seems like you have to do hax for different browsers... Maybe CSS3 has a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but this is where I got the idea of webkit/moz transform. But these rotate the whole div instead of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but why not include an extra `<div>` between your current `<div>` and your text, with a transparent background? You can then rotate that `<div>`.

Comment: Yup.. that sounds reasonable. That would have been my brute force way ahead if there wasn't something simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in a span and set it to inline-block. 
Notice how the parent div doesn't not rotate together with the text.

```
<div class="roundedOne">
  <span class="rotate">TEXT</span>
</div>

.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.roundedOne {
  background: red;
}
```

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/JEOKzw

Answer (score 0):

since the transform rotates the whole div section, you can set the height and width of the div containing the text and then transform it.